# Adding geometric tolerance in Autocad using Autolisp

Tags: window, arguments, autocad, autolisp

I am attempting to draw geometric tolerances using Autolisp script. However, I have only found (command "tolerance") to pull up the geometric tolerance window. Does anyone know how to add more arguments? My goal is to draw a parallelism symbol with a tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You don't  need to draw it geometricaly. maybe It's enought to set symbol as text by Unicode? propably symbol of parallelism has code /U+2225 it's now You need t o find font containing that symbol